# How to set the listview height base on the total height of items?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-view

I have already set the listview height like this, the function work fine, however, when some item in the listview is VIEW.GONE at the beginning, and VISIBLE at later on , the view is **not** update so latter part of the element is exceed the screen and can not show. How to fix the problem?

**1. this is the code to set the listview height base on the total height of items**

```
 public static void updateListViewHeight(ListView myListView) {
        ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
        if (myListAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        // get listview height
        int totalHeight = 0;
        int adapterCount = myListAdapter.getCount();
        for (int size = 0; size < adapterCount; size++) {
            View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        // Change Height of ListView
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (adapterCount - 1));
        myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
     }
```

**2. And the way to initialize listview** , which works fine except in the case there is hidden element and want to show later on in the listview

```
private void initCommentData() {
    customAdapter = new CommentAdapter(ctx, R.layout.item_list_detail, comment_list);
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    Utility.updateListViewHeight(listView);
    comment.requestFocus();
    scroll.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**3. This is how I toogle the hidden element**

```
reply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if(comment_bar.isShown()){
                                comment_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                reply.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.reply) + " +");
                            }else{
                                comment_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                reply.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.reply) + " -");
                            }

                            updateListViewHeight(listView);
                        }
                    });
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you try with View.INVISIBLE instead of View.GONE and see if it makes any changes ? GONE affects other views that depend on the view you're cating it on.

Comment: Did you try to call updateListViewHeight again?

Comment: yes at 3. reply.setOnClickListener

Comment: @MelihcanAksoy, it works for sure, but leave a empty space there

Answer (score 1):

Calling `setVisibility` doesn't mean that view will immediately changes size. Layout process must occur before calling `updateListViewHeight` method. In this example I used handler, another solution is to add layout listener.

```
        reply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(comment_bar.isShown()){
                comment_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                reply.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.reply) + " +");
            }else{
                comment_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                reply.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.reply) + " -");
            }
            comment_bar.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                updateListViewHeight(listView);
            }, 500);
        }
    });
```

Comment: unfortuantely still the same problem